# Access violation help C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, access-violation

I am currently getting this error in my code: Unhandled exception at 0x0FF321E8 (msvcp110d.dll) in bankAccountp5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCF8. And I'm certain it's to do with an array of objects I have created.

Here is part of my code:

```
class bankAccount: public bankBranch
{


public:

bankAccount(int, int, int, string, int);

int setAccountNumber () 
{ 
    bankAccountNumber = ++minAccountNumber;
    return this->bankAccountNumber;
}

void setAccountBalance ()
{ 
    for(i = 0; i < getNumOfBankAccounts(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the balance for your bank Account: " << endl;
        cin >> accounts[i]->bankAccountBalance;
        if (bankAccountBalance > MAX_BALANCE || bankAccountBalance < MIN_BALANCE)  
        {
            cout << "Incorrect bank balance, please try again!" <<  endl;
            --i;
        } else { 

            ++i;
        } 


}
}
void menuSystem(int choice) { 

}

void displayBankBranchDetails()
{   
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "DETAILS OF YOUR BANK BRANCH" << endl;
    cout << "BSB Number: " << this->getBsbNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << this->getAddress() << endl;
    cout << "Postal code: " << this->getPostCode() << endl;
}

void setBankAccountDetails() { 
}
int getNumOfBankAccounts() {
    return this->numOfBankAccounts;
}
void createBankAccounts()
{
valid = false;
while (valid == false) {
    cout << "How many Bank Accounts would you like to create under the Bank     Branch BSB: " << getBsbNumber() << endl;
    cin >> numOfBankAccounts;
    if ( numOfBankAccounts <= MAX_NUMBER_ACCOUNTS)
    {
        valid = true;
    } else { 

        valid = false;
    }
} 
}

private:
//bankAccount Data 
int bankAccountNumber;
int numOfBankAccounts;
int bankAccountBalance;
int interestRate;

//constants
const static int MAX_NUMBER_ACCOUNTS = 10;
const static int MAX_BALANCE = 100000;
const static int MIN_BALANCE = 0;

//objects
bankBranch homeBranch;
bankAccount* accounts[MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS];


//misc
int minAccountNumber;
int i;
bool valid;
};
```

The error occurs when I get to void setAccountBalance(), and I call the array of objects accounts, could anyone help me out with this? Cheers.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger. It will show you _exactly_ where the crash is, as well as let you examine the function call stack and values of variables.

Comment: Have you ever initialized the `accounts` array? With the information you've given it looks like the `bankAccount` pointers of it haven't been set to valid objects.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
bankAccount* accounts[MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS];
```

creates an array of pointers.  You need to take the next step of actually allocating memory for each account. Something like

```
accounts[some-index] = new bankAccount();
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm quite new to C++ and would appreciate the help.

Comment: Just updated my answer.  Some-index would vary between 0 and numOfBankAccounts.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared an array of pointers, you have to assign memory to it dynamically, bankAccount* accounts[MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS];

moreover you don't need to write the else part in setAccountBalance()

Answer (score 1):

`accounts = new bankAccount[MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS];` needs to be done in one of your functions. You have declared a dynamic array, but still need to initialize it.

EDIT: You should really consider using stl structure *vector*. This will allow you to just push new accounts into your array and a variety of other things. Using pointers and dynamically allocated arrays need you to manage your memory and other such unnecessary pains. 
Check this out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Add `using std::vector` after your inclusions. This way you don't need to keep typing std::vector, you can just say vector.

Then, `vector<bankAccount> accounts` will declare a vector called accounts. When adding new accounts, you can just call `accounts.push_back(_______)`. You can access elements with `[]` and you also have `accounts.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @scottwilson said. Instead use a `std::vector<bankAccount>` that contain statically allocated `bankAccount`s.

Else, you might have to allocate memory for each `bankAccount` pointer, either statically or as you might require, dynamically.

You also need a `createBankAccount()` function that will allocate this for you whenever you want another `bankAccount` object:

like so:

```
public:
   void createBankAccount() {
       accounts[getNumberOfBankAccounts()] = new bankAccount();
       numOfBankAccounts++;
   }
```

Call this function each time you need a new bank account.